# Can I port a Linux DMA driver to Windows?

Tags: windows, driver, device, device-mapper

I want to run it on Windows without a significant change.

I hope, I can change only headers and corresponding functions.

http://www.alterawiki.com/wiki/File:G2x4_avmm_dma_Linux.tar.gz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can, if you have a brain of a programmer, know well C, asm, and computer architecture, and have around 2-4 years to learn driver programming on windows and on linux as well.

But if you have all of these, you will be able to get a job with at least thousands dollar (euro) on the best places of the world, or even to get an IT work visa into them if you weren't enough lucky to born indoors already.

Anyways, you will surely better outcome if you buy a device with a working windows driver.

But don't forget: the driver interface between linux and windows differs a *lot*. Yes, really a *lot*. No, it won't be so simply that you simply changes some header. You will practically have to rewrite the driver. It is not as with the high-level languages, a simple porting/wrapper classes won't be enough.

There are some linux drivers who are ported from win and it is very visible on them, and yet more who are using practically an OS-independent internal layer (which is distributed often only as binary), with an OS-dependant outer source. But these structural decisions was made at the beginning of the development.

As an alternative solution, you could try some virtualization solution on a linux, and sharing the device with the alternate OS.

Comment: Is there any short example for showing how different they are?

Comment: @snow Windows has a "Driver Development Kit", which contains the headers and the needed information. For Linux, the best if you start with a simple (small) driver for a similar hardware, and customize it. Best if you try with some "pilot project", thus you write some driver only for show how they are working. And later you can add the code which initializes the hardware, communicates with it, and finally which implements all needed functions, which this actual driver interface needs.

Comment: @snow After you are ready with a very simple, very basic pilot "driver", which builds, loads into the kernel and does "something", from that point you are already in winning position.